# Copy value of column c of sheet 2 to column c of sheet 1 if columns a and b of sheets 1 and 2 match

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets of data.  Sheet one contains a last name in column A and a first name in column B.  Sheet two contains a last name in column A and a first name in column B and an email address in column C.  Sheet 2 contains many more rows than that of Sheet 1.  I want to compare both columns A and B of the two sheets and return the corresponding column C to Sheet 1 if they match.  I have not been able to find a formula or VBA code to compare two columns simultaneously and return a value if they both match.  Please help.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried to solve your issue. Also please check [Stackoverflow question checklist](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) to help you improve how you ask your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Index & Match](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/07/12/check-multiple-criteria-with-excel-index-and-match/), in column C of the First sheet. You will need to hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter after you enter this in the formula bar so that excel knows it's an array formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(1,(A1=Sheet2!A:A)*(B1=Sheet2!B:B),0))
```

A word of caution, if it's possible you are much better off using designated ranges like A1:A100/B1:B100 in the MATCH() formula instead of the whole column as it creates a massive array if you are using the entire column with A:A/B:B.

Comment: Thank you so much.  It worked perfectly.  When I limited the array it copied the change in cell number down, this did not have any adverse affect, but just wanted to mention.  If I could vote it up, I would.  Thank you again, as this saved me considerable amounts of time.